# Trying to simplify exception message but it's not being caught

Tags: c#, exception

I'm attempting to shorten an exception that is being output to a log file. The exception is occurring but the contains is not working how I intended it.

This is the message:

> !Dropbox Success Message: System.AggregateException: One or more
> errors occurred. ---> System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: An error
> occurred while sending the request. ---> System.Net.WebException: The
> request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel.    at
> System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetRequestStream(IAsyncResult
> asyncResult, TransportContext& context)    at
> System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler.GetRequestStreamCallback(IAsyncResult
> ar)    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---    at
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
> task)    at
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
> task)    at
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task task)
> at
> Dropbox.Api.DropboxRequestHandler.d__18.MoveNext()
> --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---

This is what I'm trying to do:

```
  catch (Exception e)
  {
    if (e.ToString().Contains("Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel"))
    {
      _report.Add($"!Exception occurred in SendToDropbox.");
      _report.Add($"!Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel.");
    }
    else
    {
      _report.Add($"!Exception occurred in SendToDropbox.");
      _report.Add($"!{e}");
    }
```

The `.contains` isn't catching the message in the exception. The odd thing is, the exception is being output with that phrase in it so I don't understand why the contains wouldn't catch it.

Why isn't the contains catching it? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You catch an AggregateException. The message of that AggregateException is: "_One or more errors occurred._". That's it. Read up on AggregateException's. They _aggregate_ / _consolidate_ multiple exceptions which are accessible throuth the AggregateException's InnerExceptions property. If you want to find the error message you are looking for, you have to search through those "inner" exceptions. (Side note: Exception types other than AggregateException can also "contain" one other "inner" exception, which you possibly might also need to check for the error message you are looking for...)

Comment: TLS is done before the HTTPS request is sent and usually is done in the operating system. To capture the exception you would need to override the Certificate validation.  See following for sample code : https://www.meziantou.net/custom-certificate-validation-in-dotnet.htm.  When TLS fails the request is not sent so your code in .EndGetRequestStream() never gets executed.

Comment: @MySkullCaveIsADarkPlace I understand that it's the inner exception that I'm not seeing but why would the next line `_report.Add($"!{e}");` grab the entire tls message, which contains that line but the `.contains` does not?

Comment: @SomeoneSpecial, good question. What overloads are available for the \_report.Add method? Note that an interpolated string `$"..."` in itself is not only implictly convertible to a string, but also to a _FormattableString_ (or another _IFormattable_). Perhaps \_report.Add has overloads for one of these types, thus possibly allowing for custom processing of the interpolation expressions...

Comment: @MySkullCaveIsADarkPlace thanks for getting back with me. `private static List<string> _report;` is only a list that I'm adding the messages I get to.

Comment: Hmm, i just checked. e.ToString() does indeed include the inner exception messages, and it doesn't seem to introduce line breaks for long-ish exception messages, either. Beats me, i have no clue what's going on there... (has there perhaps been some of those weird "invisible" Unicode control/formatting characters accidentally slipped into the string literal in the `if (e.ToString().Contains("Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel"))` line in your source code? I am just grasping at straws here...)

Comment: lol yeah, I have no idea either! Thanks for the the assist though!

Comment: What is the value of `e.ToString()` in your debugger?

Comment: @Wyck I can't duplicate it on my computer. It's happening on a client's machine. I wish I could otherwise I'm sure I'd know the answer by now. :(